# How to populate the data from external database to UItableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to populate the data from the external database using a PHP script, and I can see the data has been received in `viewdidload()`. But I am not able to see the data in the tableview.

I tried using the breakpoint, but no luck as my program does not reach to

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell { ....}
```

Can you please suggest what I am not doing correctly.

```
import UIKit

class UsersViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

    var data: NSArray = []

    @IBOutlet weak var listTableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        data = dataOfJson(url: "http://kpstudio18.com/app/select.php")
        print("data are as \(data)")
    }

    func dataOfJson(url: String) -> NSArray {
        var data = NSData(contentsOf: NSURL(string: url)! as URL)
        var error: NSError?
        var jsonArray: NSArray = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSArray
        return jsonArray
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if data.count != 0 {
            return data.count
        } else {
            return 1
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: additionInfoCell = self.listTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell") as! additionInfoCell
        let maindata = (data[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary)
        cell.name.text = maindata["name"] as? String
        cell.info.text = maindata["id"] as? String

        print("Cell Name is \(cell.name.text)")
        print("Cell Info (id) is \(cell.info.text)")
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the UITableView Delegate and Datasource?

Comment: Yes I have, but I am not able to get the details on the label (cell label). Cell Label have 2 label: name and info

Comment: if you are use customcell than you forgot to resister nib file in viewdidiload.

Comment: @RB1509 so how can i register it? thanks

Comment: wait i will show you.

Comment: logs are print currectly or not?

Comment: YEs there are printing in the output appropriately but not the info cell text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169554/discussion-between-rb1509-and-kunal-parekh).

Comment: Do not use `NSArray, NSDictionay, NSURL, NSError, NSData` and all other classes with `NS` prefix in Swift if there is a native equivalent. And never load data from a remote URL synchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
yourtableview_name.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "customCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
```

try this in `viewdidload`.if it works let me know.

Comment: Hey but I have two labels in the cell. Name and Info. I am only able to get the Name Label but not the info label in the cell

Answer (score 0):

You simply forgot to reload your table. In your viewDidLoad() method add the following line `yourTableView.reloadData()` and hopefully it will work.

Also, check if you registered your "CustomCell" as said above by RB1509